# How to update a remote and local branch from the remote repository?

Tags: git, egit

I have a remote from which I fetched a remote tracking branch. Iv'e checked out the branch into a local branch. The configuration is as follows:

```
Branches
-- Local
   -- remoteName/master
-- Remote Tracking 
   -- remoteName/master

Remtoes
-- remoteName
```

I want to sync changes from the remote repository's master branch into the remote tracking branch `remoteName/master`. If I right click on it, I don't see an option of doing it:

[image]

What I have to do is go to the remote and fetch, but that can fetch all the branches, unless I configure it specifically for this fetch. I don't want to reconfigure the fetch for every branch I want to update, I want to fetch for a selected branch. Can it be done?

Then I want to review the remote branch locally, so I click Check Out and am asked to create a new local branch (or work in Headless mode), but I already have a local branch which is configured to the correct remote/upstream branch:

[image]

I can't pull changes from the remote branch to it either, a right click gives:

[image]

I have to delete the current local branch and then create a new one when checking out the remote branch. Why can I not update the changes from the remote branch and the remote repository?

Comment: _but that can fetch all the branches_ ... why is that such a problem?

Comment: @Adam because there are many old and unused branches in that repo

Comment: It will only happen once, after which you'll be up to date on everything. And, unless those old-and-unused branches contain many gigabytes of otherwise-unused material, it will add about 0.003 seconds to the total fetch time. :-) (OK, maybe slightly more, but really, *branches* in Git are nearly zero cost.)

Comment: @Mark, if they're old an unused then they won't slow you down as torek says. in egit you can right click your Repository in the Repositories view and choose Fetch. I think that's all you need.

Comment: @Adam i wish it was all I need, but as i wrote I can't check out the branches properly. The remote branch is "detached" from the local one as I wrote.

Comment: @torek It's about the visual clutter of having 10 branches and using 1.

Comment: I work with repositories with 50+ remote-tracking names (`git branch -r | wc -l` gives me 72 in one right now), so I have no sympathy at all for that. :-) From command-line Git you could, manually and rather painfully, set your Git up to update just a few remote-tracking names, if you wanted, which would keep the visual clutter down. Whether you can do that in EGit, and if so how, I have no idea.

Comment: @torek and what about updating the local branch (check out of the remote branch)? as I said in my question, I need to create a new local branch each time even though one is already configured to the remote branch.

Comment: Well, again, in command-line Git, I'd just do `git fetch` followed by `git checkout <name>; git merge --ff-only`. (I have an alias for that, `git mff`, because I prefer to avoid `git pull`. Many other CLI users use `git pull` which runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge` without `--ff-only`, but I want my merge to abort if a true merge is required, so I can decide whether to merge or to rebase.) As for what to do in EGit, I have no idea.